# vue: Populate select options dynamically

Tags: vue.js

I have vuejs based application with with a form with a drop-down menu. The options in the menu should eventually be populated from a rest call. Right now I use a very hard coded list:

```
<template>
  <ModalForm v-show="visible" @close="visible = false" title="Add location">
    <div class="form-outline mb-4">
      <select
        class="form-control form-control-lg"
        placeholder="Organisation"
        v-model="formData.organisation"
      >
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center mt-5">
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
        Add location
      </button>
    </div>
  </ModalForm>
</template>

<script setup>
import { reactive, ref } from "@vue/reactivity";
import { watch } from "@vue/runtime-core";
import ModalForm from "../../../components/ModalForm.vue";

const visible = ref(false);
const formDataDefaults = {
  organisation : "",
};
const formData = reactive({ ...formDataDefaults });


watch(visible, async (newValue) => {
  if (newValue == false) {
    for (var key in formData) formData[key] = formDataDefaults[key];
  }
});

function show() {
  visible.value = true;
}

defineExpose({ show });
</script>
```

and that kind of works - but when I try to populate the select options in a slightly more dynamic way things fail in the build stage. From googling around I have tried this:

```
<option v-for="org in organisations" :value="org.name" :key="org.id">
...
<script setup>
export default {
   data() {
       return { organisation: [{name: "Org1", id: 1}, {name: "Org2", id: 2}] };
   }
};
</script>
```

When compiling/running this with `npm run serve` I get the following error message:

```
 error  in ./src/pages/Locations/components/AddLocationModal.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=js

Syntax Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'content')
```

which I do not understand, but I think it is related to the `data` export in the `<script>` section. Of course the next step is to actually populate with a rest call - but one step at a time.

Any hints appreciated!

Disclaimer: I am quite new to vue (and anything beyond basic JS), so this is in it's entirety based on CopyPaste and Google.

Update: the error message comes when I only add the

```
<script setup>
export default {
   data() {
       return { organisation: [{name: "Org1", id: 1}, {name: "Org2", id: 2}] };
   }
};
</script>
```

part - without making any changes to the `<template>` part. So it seems there is "something" wrong with the data export. I guess problem is I struggle to understand the model for flow of data/state in this framework.

Update 2: As pointed out in answer below there was a missing `{` in the original `data export` section. Fixing that did not solve the problem.

Update 3/solution: As pointed out by several I had a mix of vue2 and vue3 syntax. This [example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9kcFugzAMhl/FyoVNKnBHtFK3B9hhuy07dGBWKkgiJ9BJKO8+h1DWrVJvcf5fn3/bk9gbk40DikKUtqLWOLDoBrOTqu2NJgcTEDbgoSHdQ8LWRCqpKq1ssHZYOaxhG0wPyT55/BW1cS0/Fu1dKmCWw29XQPKiMNnAeOgG5GqfgN/80d/O+kp/utWPhNeEZ3ZI9cHdyzyOwQNw4bA33cEhVwBljAtj2usau60Ul/xSzAa2xNBsaTSxYSlbdZlGCijmpquYzeVK4JDTYs5CWPAcbEbn8TdGyWPrOaV0Zd2Ou9clTBEI62a9L/OghsnWacRGxOuk/cFkJ6sV328KYLkIHJQ5sbMUfLVQS3F0ztgiz21ThaufbKbpK+dXRoNybY8Z2j79JH22SAyWYt77wuDQNCKlhKpGQrrH/Ge94QYsb8YL/wO7s9so) solved it for me.

Comment: it will be awesome if you can isolate this issue in a jsFiddle or similar

Comment: the error says you have some object that is null but you are trying to access a property on that object called "content".  since the object is null, it cant access the property, resulting in the error.  is there anywhere in your AddLocationModal.vue file where you are trying to use a `content` property?  if there is, and you can't figure out why the object is null giving you that error, please include that code in your question.  it doesn't seem related to the `v-for` code snippet you've given us.

Comment: I don't have `content` property which I have introduced myself (I have posted "all" my code) - but certainly there can be indirect use such a property.

Comment: @yoduh: I have updated the question - as you indicate the error is *not* related to the `v-for` - it comes just with the attempt at exporting data from the `<script setup>` section.

Comment: oh, I completely missed the fact that you're using `<script setup>`.  you're not using the correct syntax for it.  with `<script setup>` you must use Vue's Composition API which doesn't export anything.  you're using Vue's older Options API which doesn't work with script setup.  See the [docs](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html) for correct usage

Comment: by the way, you can still use the Options API with Vue 3 (and if you're using Vue 2 you must use the Options API), you just have to remove the keyword `setup` from `<script setup>` and your current code should be good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example code you have a syntax error, you're missing a brace:

```
data() {
           ˅
    return { organisation: [{name: "Org1", id: 1}, {name: "Org2", id: 2}] };
           ˄
}
```

Check the official documentation about [SELECT](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#select) or the dynamic [example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9kcFugzAMhl/FyoVNKnBHtFK3B9hhuy07dGBWKkgiJ9BJKO8+h1DWrVJvcf5fn3/bk9gbk40DikKUtqLWOLDoBrOTqu2NJgcTEDbgoSHdQ8LWRCqpKq1ssHZYOaxhG0wPyT55/BW1cS0/Fu1dKmCWw29XQPKiMNnAeOgG5GqfgN/80d/O+kp/utWPhNeEZ3ZI9cHdyzyOwQNw4bA33cEhVwBljAtj2usau60Ul/xSzAa2xNBsaTSxYSlbdZlGCijmpquYzeVK4JDTYs5CWPAcbEbn8TdGyWPrOaV0Zd2Ou9clTBEI62a9L/OghsnWacRGxOuk/cFkJ6sV328KYLkIHJQ5sbMUfLVQS3F0ztgiz21ThaufbKbpK+dXRoNybY8Z2j79JH22SAyWYt77wuDQNCKlhKpGQrrH/Ge94QYsb8YL/wO7s9so)

Comment: Thank you but the error is the same even with the missing `{`. Have updated the question

Comment: The dynamic example solved it.

Answer (score 1):

`<script setup>` is only for use in Vue 3 projects using the Composition API.  Your current code within `<script setup>` however is written using the Options API.  You can either:

1. Refactor your code to use the Composition API using [script setup](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html),
2. Remove the keyword `setup` from `<script setup>` to stick with your current code which should then work using the [Options API](https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#data).  Vue 2 projects **must** use the Options API.

Comment: Yes - thank you. I had a nagging feeling there was something with this `setup` - all the examples I found used `<script>` whereas the rest of the code I am working with used `<script setup>`. The dynamic example pointed to by @REEL above solved it for me.